# In what ways is dhtmlxtabbar different from jQuery UI tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, dhtmlx

Has anybody here tried using dhtmlxtabbar? I was wondering whether someone has already compared those two libraries and can give a good comparison on the ease of use, using it in combo with other JavaScript libraries, browser quirks, etc.

One obvious difference is the licenses being used because dhtmlx has commercial and enterprise licenses in addition to its GPL license for its stadard edition.  Another is that it is difficult to load ajaxified components with inner JavaScript codes with dhtmlxtabbar.  Other than that, I know nothing else.

So, in what ways is dhtmlxtabbar different from jQuery UI tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biggest thing is you have the jquery community behind you not a support team of a company and tons of other possibilities to use with jquery. I believe telerik, dhtmlx or the other commercial libraries provide limited use-cases compared to open-source ones.

Sinan.